# Python hadoop streaming : Setting a job name

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming

- I have a job that runs on my cluster using hadoop-streaming
- I have to start a new job for which I want to add a job name, how can I pass that option on command-line or file to setup a job name?
- In Java, you can do this by saying

> ```
> JobConf conf = new JobConf(WordCount.class);
> conf.setJobName("wordcount");
> ```

How can I do that with hadoop-streaming?

Answer (score 11):

Configure the property using the -D key=value notation:

```
-D mapred.job.name='My Job'
```

You can list a whole bunch of options by calling the streaming jar with just the `-info` argument